# Как правильно сделать запрос между двумя таблицами?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица с информацией о вестибюлях в метро и есть таблица с информацией о самих станциях:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне сделать запрос между двумя таблицами основываясь на значении внешнего ключа? Например, выбрать количество турникетов (TurnstileCount) на станции "Сокольники". База - **PostgreSQL**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это *неявное* указание `INNER JOIN`, работает для SQLite, и возможно работает для PostgreSQL))):

```
SELECT LOBBY.TurnstileCount
FROM LOBBY, STATION
WHERE STATION.StationID = LOBBY.StationID AND STATION.Name = "Сокольники"
```

`WHERE STATION.StationID = LOBBY.StationID` является ключом

Это *явное* указание `LEFT JOIN`, должно работать в PostgreSQL, так как взято из учебника:

```
SELECT LOBBY.TurnstileCount
FROM LOBBY
LEFT JOIN STATION ON STATION.StationID = LOBBY.StationID
WHERE STATION.Name = "Сокольники"
```

`ON STATION.StationID = LOBBY.StationID` является ключом

Comment: *Это неявное указание `LEFT JOIN`* Ошибаетесь. Это `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Да, вы правы, исправил

Comment: 'SELECT TurnstileCount.LOBBY...' нужно перевернуть LOBBY.TurnstileCount. Касается и остальных

Comment: Да блин)))) каждый раз запарываюсь на этом))) Всё время хочется написать КОЛОНКА.ТАБЛИЦА)))))